# Binary logic in prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to solve following problem using inference making power of prolog.

One day, 3 persons, a, b, c were caught by police at the crime spot. When police settled interrogating them:

```
i) a says I am innocent
ii) b says a is criminal
iii) c says I am innocent.
```

Its known that

```
i) Exactly one person speaks true.
ii) Exactly one criminal is there.
```

Who  is  criminal?
To model above problem in First Order logic:
Consider c/1 is a predicate returns true when argument is Criminal 
we can write:

```
(not(c(a)),c(c)) ; (c(c),c(a)).
 c(a); c(b); c(c).
(not(c(a)),not(c(b))) ; (not(c(a)),not(c(c))) ; (not(c(b)),not(c(c))).
```

After modelling above statements in prolog, I will query:

```
?-c(X).
it should return:
X=c.
But error I got:
"No permission to modify static procedure `(;)/2'"
```

Comment: You are writing arbitrary formulas but Prolog only accepts Horn formulas, i.e. of the form ```fact.``` or ```head :- goal1, goal2, goal3.```.  It's also pretty confusing that you have person ```c``` and a predicate ```c```.

Comment: @lambda.xy.x 
I am trying to write NL1:

"Exactly one among a,b,c speaks true"

in the FOL: 
"(not(criminal(a)),criminal(c)) ; (criminal(c),criminal(a))."
and NL2: 
"exactly one among a, b, c is criminal"
in the FOL:
" criminal(a); criminal(b); criminal(c).
(not(criminal(a)),not(criminal(b))) ; (not(criminal(a)),not(criminal(c))) ; (not(criminal(b)),not(criminal(c)))."

How can we express this in horn formulas so that it will become syntactically correct prolog program while keeping the semantic same?

Comment: You are trying to directly translate the formula which doesn't work that well (e.g. to make sure the predicate criminal(X) has only one solution, you would need to write "criminal(X) -> not exists Y: different(Y,X), criminal(Y)"). @topologicalsort is already pointing you into the right direction by making your state space explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Since PROLOG does indeed work with Horn clauses, you'll need things of form `head :- tail`, reading `:-` as "if."

```
solve(Solution) :- ...
%With a Solution looking something like: 
% solve(a(truth,innocent),b(false,criminal),c(false,innocent)).
```

To use the generate and test method, which is a common and reasonable way to solve this, you'd do something like this:

```
solve(Solution) :-
  Solution = [a(_,_),b(_,_),c(_,_)],
  generate(Solution), 
  validate(Solution).
```

`generate` should give you a well-formed `Solution`, that is, one having all the variables filled in with values that make some kind of sense (that is, `false, true, criminal, innocent`).

`validate` should ensure that the Solution matches the constraints you gave.

`solve` only completes when one of `generate`'s solutions makes it past `validate`'s constraints.

For an introduction to the generate and test method, see [this tutorial](http://gki.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/teaching/ws0708/logic/prolog9.pdf).

But if you're writing code that isn't Horn clauses, you might need a tutorial on writing PROLOG functions (OK, relations), like [this one](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/Concise%20Guides/Concise%20Prolog.html#writing).